# 3pin (GND, 12V, tach) 12v FAN control using PWM

Tags: pwm

I know there are fans out there that have a dedicated PWM input, but I like to know if I can PWM control a fan that does not have such a dedicated PWM input. So...

If I have a 3 pin 12v fan like the [Noctua NF-A20](https://noctua.at/en/products/fan/nf-a20-flx) with connections:

- GND
- 12 V
- tach out (RPM measurement)

Can I control its speed by PWM on the 12V supply voltage (using a MOSFET most probably)?
Would the tach out still work?

Comment: I think that is OK AFAIK, I remember controlling my car's robot normal DC motor with PWM very well, yet the only  thing I hate about it is it did make a lot of noise, yet I used this noise to generate a small tone when I turn on the robot :)

Comment: you can run such fans at 5v too, many do to keep them silent...

Comment: I am powering from usb 5v. I could implement a arduino controlled step up boost 5v-12v’(eg based on mt3608) instead of pwm. Wondering what what be best pure voltage controlled or pwm....

Comment: Or straight from i2c like here https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp8859-integrated-dc-dc-buck-boost-converter-with-i2c-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and yes.

You have to modulate the +12V rather than GND because the output is referenced to ground. That means you need to use the classic N+P channel FET arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHOe8H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why 2 mosfets? One fet berween 12 and fan 12v controlled directly from the arduino should work no? (With pull down on gate of course)

Comment: @HixField The Arduino's 5V logic level is too low to switch off the P fet. It is possible to emulate M2 with the GPIO by using LOW for on and INPUT for off, but you can't do that with PWM. M2 turns the Arduino's GPIO into "open drain" and is used to turn M1 on and off.

Comment: I would use a logic level fet such as the http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3400A.pdf that works straight from 5v logic

Comment: What I dont understand is how the tach output can still work if the fan is not powered (briefly by pwm)? Is it using a mechanical contact?

Comment: @HixField logic level has nothing to do with it; 5v and 0v are both "on" states given a ~12v source on a p-chan fet.

Comment: @dandavis I would think this would also work? https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/using-mosfets-with-ttl-levels/ this means switching on the low side?

Comment: the 12v is the problem, and getting an ardunio to 11v is just as hard as getting it to 9v. When sinking with an n-chan, 5v turns on the vast majority of nfets, but 3.3v is usually too little for all but logic level specs. When sourcing with a pchan, vgs-th is subtracted from the source voltage, not added to the source voltage.

Comment: Ah I get it. We must have a stable GND because the tach otherwise would fail! So we must switch on the high side hence the 2 fet setup

Comment: bingo. i actually would switch the common with a simple nchan fet; i don't think the tach needs 12v anyway. you can pull the n-chan down with a npn bjt as well. there's also several opto-isolators that can drop-in as well, no fet needed.

Comment: @dandavis The "tach" is a hall effect sensor. If you switch the "common" (ground) then you don't have a ground for the tach's output circuit, so you don't get proper readings (i.e., you only get readings when the N-fet is on, and garbage when it's off). It's essential to switch the +12V and not the ground.

Comment: thanks for this great info and help!

Comment: @Majenko: interesting. from what i can tell you're right, but i've used sink pwm and tach in a esp-32 based PSU project and it worked. Maybe the pwm frequency was high enough, the rpm low enough, and the intrinsic capacitance high enough that it worked out...

Comment: @dandavis Quite possibly. You want the PWM to be >25kHz to avoid and the RPM will be below 3000 RPM typically.

Comment: Could the tach input pin use the Arduino's internal pullups? or are those (20-50k) too low-value for a clean waveform at fan RPMs?